# Custom thread scheduling in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I've a long running task which consist of 2 parts. First part is intensive I/O operation (and almost no CPU), second part is intensive CPU operation. I would have 2 threads running this task so that CPU part of the task in one thread is bound to I/O part of this task running by another thread. In other words, I would like to run CPU-intensive part in `thread #1` while `thread #2` runs I/O operation and vise versa, so I utilize maximum CPU and I/O.

Is there some generic solution in Java for more then 2 threads?

Answer (score 0):

Make a class which extends Thread. Now make two objects of that class and handle your logic of I/O and CPU part in two separate functions.

Comment: JVM/OS scheduling will not guarantee that my tasks will execute strictly bounded if I split my IO/CPU into 2 separate tasks. Or it will?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the Executors class:

```
//Create a thread pool
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

//Launch a new thread
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Asynchronous task");
    }
});

//Try to terminate all the alive threads
executorService.shutdown();
```

This may help you:
[Task Execution and Scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is possible. The scheduling of threads is fundamentally handled by the operating system. The OS decides which thread is run on which logical CPU. On the level of the application you can only give some hints to the OS scheduler, like priority, but you cannot force a certain scheduling.

It might be possible with languages like C or C++ by invoking OS specific APIs, but on the abstraction layer on Java you cannot force that behaviour.

Comment: That's possible at least by using a lock which is shared between threads and is simultaneously exclusive. This lock will be acquired right between intensive IO and CPU. This is simplest manual solution, but I'm looking for some generic approach which I'm assured must exist.

Answer (score 0):

splitting the work in 2 threads is an artifical constraint, and as any artifacal constraint, it can only limit the level of parallelism. If two parts are logically sequential (e.g. io work must preceede the cpu intensive work in order to provide data), then they should be executed sequentially on the same thread. If you have several independent tasks, they should be executed on different threads. Problems may arise if you have thousand of threads and they eat too much memory. Then you have to split your work in tasks and run that tasks on a thread pool (executor service). This is more complicated approach as you may need to coordinate starting of your tasks but there are no standard means to do so. One of solutions to coordinate small tasks is actor execution model, but it is impossible to say beforehand if actor model fits your needs.

Comment: Yes, I/O work should precede CPU intensive work, thus both tasks should be executed in the same thread. My question was how to synchronize those threads so they don't try to execute both CPU intensive parts at the same time (considering that we've a single core system and each CPU intensive part loads CPU fully. As the result - overloading of CPU). And does not overload I/O (considering that each I/O part will fully utilize I/O bandwidth).

Comment: what do yo mean by "overloading of CPU"? If there is something to compute, CPU works. If not, stops. If work is added while CPU is occupied, the work is placed in a queue - on O/S level, the queue of ready threads. All you can do is to replace O/S queue by your own queue (and represent work in other form than threads) - but you cannot prevent "overloading of CPU", since it is an imaginary thing (unlike stack or numeric overflow).